# Is there any word for a place full of confusion?

Tags: single-word-requests, literary-english

I am searching for a word for a place which is full of confusion. I tried searching but couldn't find any link.

This website mentions nothing.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/confused

Merriam-Webster says Labyrinth, but I find that a bit mainstream.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/labyrinth

**I am looking for some mythical or literary reference. Can anyone help me?**

EDIT:

I am looking for something which I can use in a sentence like

> "The attractive offers sent me into a ..........".

And I am desiring a mythical reference.

Comment: Do you mean "a place full of confusion" or "a place which is confusing"? A labyrinth is confusing to be in but is not, necessarily, full of confusion. On the other hand it is quite possible to have a simple space, even an open field, where a large number of people are gathered with no organisation and no clear direction. This happens all too often in refugee camps for example. Such a place would be "full of confusion" but would not, necessarily, be "a confusing space"

Comment: Thanks. That's a really good explanation. I am looking for something which I can use in a sentence like "The attractive offers sent me into a ..........". And I am desiring a mythical reference.

Comment: Note that everything you're getting here has a negative connotation, which doesn't match very well with `attractive offers`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't see a mismatch.  (I am interpreting it as "The offers were  attractive, but they turned out to lead me to ...".)

Comment: It's not an answer, but my initial reaction to just the title was "House of Commons".

Comment: Well, since someone didn't like my earlier suggestion, how about "zoo"?  And there may well be a mythical or literary version of this.

Comment: My initial thought would have been "Madhouse", but considering the edit it doesn't really fit into your sentence. "The attractive offers sent me into a [whirlwind of emotions](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-whirlwind-of-emotions-activity-etc)" would seem fitting; it carries no negative connotation and conveys the message, but it's neither single-word nor particularly mythical... it's also not a literal place.

Comment: The title asks for ***disjointed*** : "lacking orderly continuity" - "lacking order or coherence" - "disconnected; incoherent" - *"a confused set of instructions"; "a confused dream about the end of the world"; "disconnected fragments of a story"; "scattered thoughts"* – [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/disjointed)

Answer (score 22):

**Bedlam** is exactly the word you are looking for. The name comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethlem_Royal_Hospital

or Bedlam : an asylum for the mentally ill
a place, scene, or state of uproar and confusion

Comment: I mostly see "bedlam" used for the "state of uproar" more than just confusion. So more like a train station when several trains arrive simultaneously rather than inner turmoil.

Comment: Bedlam does imply confusion, and while stations can get very crowded most of the people there are not confused.

Comment: I have certainly seen "bedlam" used to describe an inner mental state. Most memorably in the title of the 2003 interactive fiction game "[Slouching Towards Bedlam](https://ifdb.tads.org/viewgame?id=032krqe6bjn5au78)"

Comment: Or, similarly, "madhouse." The place was a total madhouse.

Answer (score 21):

There is the word [**pandemonium**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pandemonium):

> [Oxford Dictionaries]
> Wild and noisy disorder or confusion; uproar.
> ‘there was complete pandemonium—everyone just panicked’
> ‘I knew that a lack of heir undoubtedly lead to pandemonium and anarchy.’
>
> **Origin**
> Mid 17th century: modern Latin (denoting the place of all demons, in Milton's Paradise Lost), from pan- ‘all’ + Greek daimōn ‘demon’.

As [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pandemonium) further clarifies:

> **2** *capitalized* : the capital of Hell in Milton's *Paradise Lost*
> **3** *capitalized* : the infernal regions : HELL
> // the demons of *Pandemonium*

So, you could talk *about pandemonium* or you could say that you sent somebody *to Pandemonium*.

The [enotes website](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/discuss-how-devils-build-pandemonium-paradise-lost-749513) describes the nature of Pandemonium:

> Indeed, the haste with which Pandemonium appears serves to highlight its lack of permanence and the underlying instability of its foundations. This is a fake construction; an attempt to replicate the splendours of heaven. Yet this it can never do as it has been put together by mere worldly materials, and as such can never provide more than a glittering facade for the evil machinations of Satan and his devilish acolytes. Milton helps us see beyond this facade and, in doing so, provides an abiding insight into the things that truly matter.

No doubt this sense of instability and its fake nature is what led the word to take on its current meaning of confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much. This seems to be exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: @PranjalSinghal If you are satisfied then please accept the answer.

Comment: I would suggest waiting instead: the question is only five hours old.

Comment: "Limbo" is another variant with similar usage and connotations to Pandemonium

Comment: Good answer, but note that pandemonium typically refers to a state of physical confusion or chaos (like shouting "fire" in a crowded theater). From the OP's stub example, they may be looking for something a more personal or internal state of confusion. I'm not sure that a single person's throughts/actions could be described as pandemonium.

Comment: Could cause confusion.  The helicopter service out of Timonium Maryland is known as the Pan-Timonium Airline.

Answer (score 10):

The noun [**turmoil**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/turmoil) immediately springs to mind. Turmoil, in very simple words, is a chaotic or confusing situation. A country might slide into economic or political turmoil after a coup d'état, for example. A person can be in a state of inner turmoil. In that case, it means a state in which a person feels deeply confused about something problematic going on in their life. The Oxford Dictionary defines this word as follows:

> A state of great disturbance, confusion, or uncertainty.

A couple of example sentences:

> He endured years of **inner turmoil**.
>
> Sitting on his bed, he felt **inner turmoil** about it again as he did on countless occasions.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Greek mythology](https://greekgodsandgoddesses.net/gods/chaos/), one of the most ancient of gods; the personification of the infinity of space preceding creation of the universe was known as Chaos.

You can use the adjective form of

> **chaos**

i.e. *chaotic* to modify the noun *[some place]*.

Though, chaotic in contemporary English means

> *Meaning:* In a state of complete confusion and disorder.
>
> > *Usage 1*. [In literal sense] The house is a bit ***chaotic*** at the moment - we've got all these extra people staying and we're still decorating.
> >
> > *Usage 2*. [In figurative sense] Her mind was a ***chaotic place*** for her fragile thoughts and Her heart was a fragile place for her chaotic feelings.

or, 
you can simply say

> It is a chaotic place.

Answer (score 3):

### Madhouse

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/madhouse

> 2. a wild, confused, and often noisy place, set of circumstances, etc.:
>    *The office was a madhouse today.*

Most other options seem to refer more to a *state* -- either the mental state of the people, or the general state of the place -- rather than the place itself. With "madhouse", the madness refers to a part of what the place *is*, not just to what's happening there.

Answer (score 1):

One word that would fit your example sentence is ***tizzy***. A tizzy is a nervous, excited, or distracted mental state. It doesn't describe a physical place of confusion, but rather a personal sense of frenetic thought. This doesn't fit the question title very well, but fits the example sentence in the question body just about perfectly.

"The attractive offers sent me into a tizzy" would mean that you are exhibiting some kind of agitation while thinking about these offers, possibly being excited, nervous, or confused about them - in other words "your head is spinning" (in a figurative sense).

[Tizzy at Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tizzy)

Comment: You beat me to it in seconds! Please add link to an online reference and this can be a good answer.